# Somar filtrando por 1 campo de uma tabela com o campo de outra tabela

Tags: where, sum

Boas tenho o seguinte código

```
Select sum (quantidade * 
            preco_unit * 
            iva/100 + quantidade * 
            preco_unit) as totalciva
From Torcamentos_aux
Where Torcamento_aux.cod_orc in 
     (select cod_orcamento 
      from torcamentos_new 
      where cod_orc=cod_orcamento)
```

As tabelas não estão indexadas e o valor total não corresponde ao valor total verdadeiro,
Podem ajudar se faz favor?

Comment: Com o código que mencionei não dava o valor certo e não atualizava os valores quando mudo de campo, mantinha sempre o mesmo valor. Com os parêntesis aumentou  casas decimais aumentando o valor e quando mudo de campo não atualiza o total, mantém o mesmo valor

Comment: Edita o post com um exemplo numérico , o que se tem e o que se quer. Se possível um exemplo no http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: sum ((quantidade * preco_unit) + ((iva/100) + (quantidade * preco_unit))) as totalciva

Comment: Não me dá o valor certo, inseri quatidade 1, preco_unit 100, iva 23 era suposto dar totalciva 123€ e dá 74 mil € eu não tenho a tabela com chave primária será disso? Quando mudo de registo o valor de 74mil mantém-se e não atualiza para o valor do registo seguinte ou qualquer outro registo

Answer (score -1):

--simulação em Oracle

```
select produto,
       (qtd * preco_unit) preco_total,
      ((iva/100) * (qtd * preco_unit)) imposto,
      round(( (qtd * preco_unit) + ((iva/100) * (qtd * preco_unit)) ),2) preco_com_imposto
from
(
select '1' produto,
      1 qtd,
      100.00 preco_unit,
      23 iva
from dual
union all
select '2' produto,
      13 qtd,
      1234.56 preco_unit,
      23 iva
from dual
) virtual--tabela em memoria 


PRODUTO PRECO_TOTAL    IMPOSTO PRECO_COM_IMPOSTO
------- ----------- ---------- -----------------
1               100         23               123 
2          16049.28  3691.3344          19740.61
```

Comment: Isso funciona pelo que vejo mas o que pretendo é que me filtre e calcule atravez do campo cod_orc da tabela que tem a quantidade, preço unitário e valor do iva,  com outra tabela que tem o cod_orcamento que é o valor a filtrar quando faço novo registo ou scroll

Comment: Faz um exemplo no Fidlle.

Comment: A condição where é que não está a funcionar, eliminei todos os registos a calcular e inseri um novo registo e calculou certo, inseri mais um novo registo em novo orçamento e a condição where não funciona, faz o calculo de todos os registos exemplo com números quantidade =1 preço unitário =1 iva=23 calculou 1,23, novo orçamento com com os mesmos valores calculou 3 e pouco, talvez seja o in que tenho no where, como faço a condição where directa tipo cod_orc=cod_orcamento? Não sei qual o codigo para fazer select de duas tabelas com condição where, o codigo da erro no Fidlle não conhece tabelas